# Locating divs with changing class names (selenium)

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, automation

I am taking a selenium course online and we are automating log ins. The lecture is outdated and the website we are using is updated (Quora).

The problem is, the input fields have *randomly generated class names* which makes the "**find_element_by_id** method useless.

I can not figure out how to log in for different sessions. *How would I select these fields during different sessions* ( that have different class names ). This is what my code looks like. Thank you in advance. I tried asking the course instructor but he hasnt responded all week.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'/Users/mpbro17/Desktop/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://www.quora.com')

driver.find_element_by_id("__w2_fy0VXDC_email").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("__w2_fy0VXDC_email").send_keys("programmingdude183@gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("__w2_fy0VXDC_password").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("__w2_fy0VXDC_password").send_keys("testpassword1")
driver.find_element_by_id("__w2_fy0VXDC_submit_button").click()
```

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mbpro/Desktop/projects/scraping_course/test_quora_login.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_name("email").clear()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 92, in clear
    self._execute(Command.CLEAR_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.143)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417412 (ac882d3ce7c0d99292439bf3405780058fcca0a6),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.5 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try css selectors instead:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id$="email"]')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id$="password"]')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id$="submit_button"]')
```

Comment: I tried this but am still getting the erorr "line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it."

Answer (score 0):

You could have used find_element_by_name method to find your elements (email and password) and cssSelector for Login button. I think, this won't make you disheartened.

```
driver.find_element_by_name("email").clear()
driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("programmingdude183@gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").clear()
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("testpassword1")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='Login']").click()
```

Comment: I tried class names and this.. I keep getting an error. I pasted it in the question

Comment: I wasn't talking about class names. There's an attribute called 'name' inside the tags your are working on. This is one of the approaches for finding  locator in selenium.

Comment: I know.. I'm just letting you know what else I tried. Finding element by name still gave me the error in the question. Did you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go with name as it standard.However there are two elements present if you go by name property.

[image]

So go by the below xpath

```
//div[@class='regular_login']//input[@name='email']
//div[@class='regular_login']//input[@name='password']
//div[@class='regular_login']//input[contains(@class,'submit')]
```

Comment: hmm, Ive never used find_element_by_xpath() How would that look? AFter many attempts. I Cant seem to figure it out